# PHP set empty field in database to value

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

My goal is set value if field is empty.

But get "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

last_day is empty field, how to assign value 1 ?

```
public function getPointsForExercises(){
        $ls = Auth::user()->lessons()->get();
        $last_day = Auth::user()->user_settings->last_day;
            if (empty($user->user_settings->last_lesson)) {
                $user->user_settings->last_lesson = 1; 
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: `$user` variable is not defined.

What you are trying to achieve can be done using the `exists` function to make sure the relation exists, and then update the value using the `update` function, like this:

```
public function getPointsForExercises() {
    $ls = Auth::user()->lessons()->get();
    $last_day = Auth::user()->user_settings->last_day;

    if (Auth::user()->user_settings()->exists() && empty(Auth::user()->user_settings->last_lesson)) {
        Auth::user()->user_settings()->update([
            'last_lesson' => 1
        ]); 
    }
```

The code above is not ending the function nor is it using the variables `$ls` and `$last_day` as your code.

Comment: still line $last_day = Auth::user()->user_settings->last_day; getting error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: If `user_settings` doesn't exist you will get an error yes. You are not checking if it exists. Could easily be solved in a one liner like this: `$last_day = (Auth::user()->user_settings()->exists() ? Auth::user()->user_settings->last_day : 'default value if it doesnt exist');`

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the $user object.

firstly you have to make object :

```
$user = Auth::user()
```